# Java - find consecutive elements in 2D array

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with an algorithm, suppose the following:
A cinema has n rows, each row consists of m seats (n and m do not exceed 20). A two-dimensional matrix stores the information on the sold tickets, number 1 means that the ticket for this place is already sold, the number 0 means that the place is available. You want to buy k tickets to the neighboring seats in the same row. Find whether it can be done.

**Input data**

On the input, the program gets the number of n rows and m seats. Then, there are n lines, each containing m numbers (0 or 1) separated by spaces. The last line contains a number k.

**Output data**

The program should output the number of the row with k consecutive available seats. If there are several rows with k available seats, output the first row with these seats. If there is no such a row, output the number 0.

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    static int findRowWithAvailableSeat(int[][] matrix, int tickets) {
        final int rows = matrix.length;
        final int columns = matrix[0].length;
        int seatCounter = 0;

        for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= columns; c++) {
                if (matrix[r][c] == 1) {
                    continue;
                } if (matrix[r][c] == matrix[r][c + 1]) {
                    seatCounter++;
                    if (seatCounter == tickets) {
                        return r;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();
        int columns = scanner.nextInt();

        int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                matrix[r][c] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int kTickets = scanner.nextInt();
        int rowWithAvailableSeats = findRowWithAvailableSeat(matrix, kTickets);
        System.out.println(rowWithAvailableSeats);
    }
}
```

I know the problem is somewhere in findRowWithAvailableSeat method. I would like a hint on how to solve the problem, not the actual solution. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I could finally solve it (or at least it works as intended, I'm not sure if it's the best implementation). Thanks you all for your tips.

```
   static int findRowWithAvailableSeat(int[][] matrix, int tickets) {
        final int rows = matrix.length;
        final int columns = matrix[0].length;
        int seatCounter;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            seatCounter = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                if (matrix[r][c] == 1) {
                    seatCounter = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                if (matrix[r][c] == 0) {
                    seatCounter++;
                    if (seatCounter == tickets) {
                        return r + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, initialize your seatcounter variable after first loop so that it starts with 0 for each row, and correct your logic to increment this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the 4 tips you need:

1. Don't compare `matrix[r][c] == matrix[r][c + 1]`. Plainly compare to 0:
   `matrix[r][c] == 0`. To avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2. As DarkSigma already pointed, start your loops iterator from 0, not 1: `for (int r = 0; r < rows...`
3. Re-init your `seatCounter` to 0 for each row.
4. And! When you print out `System.out.println(rowWithAvailableSeats)`, remember that row counting starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

1. on main() method, you set matrix from index 0 to rows-1, and from index 0 to columns-1. But on findRowWithAvailableSeat(), you start from index 1. So index 0 will never be accessed.
2. `} if (matrix[r][c] == matrix[r][c + 1]) {` this line will try to access index c+1, will result index out of bound exception. either you need to check whether or not c+1 is less than column size or compare matrix[r][c] with 0 (matrix[r][c] == 0).
3. if you looking for neighboring seats, then you need to reset the seatCounter when you visit the sold seat (matrix[r][c] == 1)
4. you also need to reset seatCounter for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops start at 1 instead of 0

```
for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 1; c <= columns; c++) {
        if (matrix[r][c] == 1) {
```

The first index of the matrix array is being skipped. So you're not checking the first row and the first seat of each row.

Also, `seatCounter` is not being reset for each row. It currently retains any seats counted from previous rows.

I'm also not sure what this is for

```
if (matrix[r][c] == matrix[r][c + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put each row in a string and all rows in a string array a[m], then do a[i].contains(k) on each row:
"1001101110100010110010".contains("000")